# Powerange - Change value via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using [Powerange](http://abpetkov.github.io/powerange/) library in my form . It is a javascript library to create iOS style range bars. There are plenty of options author has provided.

Is there any way to move slider to a particular value via javascript programmatically? Documentation doesn't has anything related to this.

Answer (score 1):

I have a same problem and write some code to move slider to a particular value via javascript programmatically. See it below.

```
/**
 * set slider new value
 * 
 * @param {object} sliderInstance 
 * @param {number} newValue       
 */

function setSliderValue (sliderInstance, newValue) {
  console.assert( (newValue > sliderInstance.options.min && newValue < sliderInstance.options.max), 
    'New value is less then slider min value or greater then slider max value!');
  var changed = false;
  var offset;
  var maxValue = sliderInstance.options.max;
  var minValue = sliderInstance.options.min;
  var stepIndex;
  var stepsArr = (sliderInstance.options.step) ? sliderInstance.steps : null;
  var value = (sliderInstance.options.decimal) ? (Math.round(newValue * 100) / 100) : Math.round(newValue);

  if (!sliderInstance.options.step) {

    var persentNewValueOfVal = (newValue - minValue) * 100 / (maxValue - minValue);
    offset = (sliderInstance.slider.offsetWidth - sliderInstance.handle.offsetWidth) * persentNewValueOfVal / 100;

  } else {

    stepIndex = ( (value - minValue)/sliderInstance.options.step ).toFixed(0);
    offset = stepsArr[+stepIndex];

  }

  changed = (sliderInstance.element.value != value) ? true : false;
  sliderInstance.setPosition(offset);
  sliderInstance.element.value = value;
  sliderInstance.options.callback();
  if (changed) sliderInstance.changeEvent();
}
```

You can use it standalone like this:

```
var elem = document.querySelector('.js-decimal');
var init = new Powerange(elem, options);

setSliderValue(init, 36);
```

Also you can update you Powerange.prototype. I input the code bellow on line 1457 in my powerange.js

```
/**
 * Set slider new value.
 * 
 * @param {number} newValue 
 */

Powerange.prototype.setSliderValue = function (newValue) {
  console.assert( (newValue > this.options.min && newValue < this.options.max), 
    'New value is less then slider min value or greater then slider max value!');
  var changed = false;
  var offset;
  var maxValue = this.options.max;
  var minValue = this.options.min;
  var stepIndex;
  var stepsArr = (this.options.step) ? this.steps : null;
  var value = (this.options.decimal) ? (Math.round(newValue * 100) / 100) : Math.round(newValue);

  if (!this.options.step) {

    var persentOfVal = percentage.from( (newValue - minValue), (maxValue - minValue) );
    offset = percentage.of( (this.slider.offsetWidth - this.handle.offsetWidth), persentOfVal );

  } else {

    stepIndex = ( (value - minValue)/this.options.step ).toFixed(0);
    offset = stepsArr[+stepIndex];

  }

  changed = (this.element.value != value) ? true : false;
  this.setPosition(offset);
  this.element.value = value;
  this.options.callback();
  if (changed) this.changeEvent();
};
```

Now you can use it in a certain way:

```
var elem = document.querySelector('.js-decimal');
var init = new Powerange(elem, options);

init.setSliderValue(36);
```

Answer (score 0):

reading the source code ...

```
/**
 * Set slider current value.
 *
 * @param {Number} offset
 * @param {Number} size
 * @api private
 */

Powerange.prototype.setValue = function (offset, size) {
  var part = percentage.from(parseFloat(offset), size)
    , value = percentage.of(part, this.options.max - this.options.min) + this.options.min
    , changed = false;

  value = (this.options.decimal) ? (Math.round(value * 100) / 100) : Math.round(value);
  changed = (this.element.value != value) ? true : false;

  this.element.value = value;
  this.options.callback();
  if (changed) this.changeEvent();
};
```

so - based on the example

```
var elem = document.querySelector('.js-range');
var init = new Powerange(elem);
```

I guess

```
init.setValue(?, ?)
```

Would do it ... not sure about the parameters ... I think they are (value, maxValue) - because a percentage is calculated in that function using offset, size ... try it and see

Comment: didn't do anything. Found out that setPosition() is the function. thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

```
init.options.max = 100;
init.options.min = 1;
```